# Webpack splitted chunks result in preload errors after build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

I wanted to build my **VueCLI App** and reduce some of the bundle sizes by splitting chunks. But after a successful build, the App didn't work in the dist folder.

I'm getting for multiple js and css files a preload error and nothing loads on the page. When I remove the configurations of Webpack in the `vue.config.js` everything works but results in a way larger bundle size. It's caused by the `lottie-web` package that takes over 500KB.

#### Console Errors:

`` The resource <URL> was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally. ``
[image]

#### Here my vue.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    index: {
      entry: 'src/main.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      title: 'Home'
    }
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch');
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
      minimize: true,
      splitChunks: {
        minSize: 10000,
        maxSize: 250000,
        cacheGroups: {
          vendors: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            name: 'vendor',
            chunks: 'all',
            priority: -20
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

#### Terminal output after build:

[image]

The routes are also only initialized when needed.
For example:

```js
const Home = () => import('@/views/Home.vue')
const About = () => import('@/views/About.vue')
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    component: About
  }
]
```